# PureScript - Could not match type Maybe String with type String

Tags: purescript

The following PureScript code attempts to log a single value from an array of strings

```
module Main where

import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Prelude
import Data.Array

x :: Array String
x = ["Jason","Zack","Billy","Trini","Kimberly"]

y :: String
y = x !! 2

main ∷ Effect Unit
main = do
  log (y)
```

However it produces the following error code:

```
  Could not match type
  
    Maybe String
  
  with type
          
    String
          

while checking that type Maybe String
  is at least as general as type String
```

It seems like the line of code

```
y = x !! 2
```

Returns a `Maybe String` instead of a `String`.

So the questions would be,

1. How do you convert the Maybe String type into the String type (providing a default value in the process)
2. Is there any other way to access an array (in this case, an array of Strings) that returns a String and not a Maybe String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert a `Maybe a` to an `a` providing a default in the process, use [`fromMaybe`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-maybe/5.0.0/docs/Data.Maybe#v:fromMaybe):

```hs
y :: String
y = x !! 2 # fromMaybe ""
```

**Pro tip:** if you're looking for a function of a particular shape, you can search Pursuit by the function signature. For example, you could have discovered `fromMaybe` by [searching for `a -> Maybe a -> a`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=a+-%3E+Maybe+a+-%3E+a). Or even more specifically [search for `String -> Maybe String -> String`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/search?q=String+-%3E+Maybe+String+-%3E+String) if you're uncomfortable with generics (though admittedly in that case `fromMaybe` appears a bit lower on the page).

---

If you're looking for "any other way" to access an array and get a `String`, you have to ask yourself: what should happen when the array has fewer than three elements? If you're asking for the third string in the array, but it contains only two, what should the result be?

Obviously there is no sane answer to that, which is why the `index` function returns a `Maybe`.

Another alternative (which FP languages tend to avoid in general) is to cause a catastrophic runtime error in that case. Such function would be called a "partial" function, meaning that it only works for *some* inputs and not for *all possible* ones. The library does provide [some partial functions on arrays in `Data.Array.Partial`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-arrays/6.0.1/docs/Data.Array.Partial), but `index` is not one of them. My guess is, nobody ever needed it.

You could make your own if you really wanted:

```hs
unsafeIndex :: forall a. Array a -> Int -> a
unsafeIndex arr idx =
  unsafePartial
    case arr !! idx of
      Just a -> a
```

Here I'm using a `case` expression that doesn't cover all possibilities (i.e. there is no `Nothing` case), which would normally cause a compilation error, but then I'm getting rid of it (or, rather, deferring it to runtime) with the [magic `unsafePartial` function](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-partial/3.0.0/docs/Partial.Unsafe#v:unsafePartial). At runtime, if given invalid index, this function would crash saying "failed pattern match".

Alternatively, I could handle the `Nothing` case, but explicitly crash on it instead of returning a value. This way I get to provide a custom error message:

```hs
unsafeIndex :: forall a. Array a -> Int -> a
unsafeIndex arr idx =
  case arr !! idx of
    Just a -> a
    Nothing -> unsafeCrashWith "Array is too short"
```

In conclusion, I'd like to reiterate that, even though such partial functions are possible, **you should avoid using them if you can**. The type system is there to *help* you, not hinder you, and if you choose to circumvent it, you're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: Just wanted to add this is really a great answer. Exactly what I needed to solve the problem at the top, all the background you could ask for in the rest of the body.